# Why the Parent on a User Control is NULL?

Tags: c#, winforms

There is an ActiveX control in the company from 1996 with VB6.0 or maybe VC6.0. Now In C# to use it we have created a user control for it.
so its class is like this:

```
**public partial class ResultNumeric : UserControl**
```

Then we also wanted to use it as a Numeric Cell Type inside the cells of a spreadsheet and we are using *Farpoint* spread.So, we also have this class for it: (EditBaseCell type is from Farpoint spread classes).

**`public class NumericCellType : EditBaseCellType`**

so with this we can insert that control inside a cell of a spread and it has a _Leave method written like this:

```
private void m_accept_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FpSpread spread = (FpSpread)((ResultNumeric)sender).Parent;
        spread.EditMode = false;
}
```

The problem is that if I have two cells with this numeric control in them and move form one to the other one so this _Leave event gets called then with the code above it will cause a Null exception because spread is null.
So with the definition on those classed above and the code above what wrong thing do you think I am doing?

Comment: I can also show the StackTrace if you need it. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't sound like `sender` is FpSpread.  Check the type of sender.

Comment: correct, when it gets null the type of sender is ResultNumeric.NumericCellType.

Comment: If you change FpSpread to just Control, is Parent still null?

Comment: yes, I changed it like you mentioned to Control and it is still NULL.  Control spread = ((ResultNumeric)sender).Parent as Control;

Comment: Then FpSpread is not in the container tree.  How many FpSpread controls do you have?  If just one, then reference the one you have.  If more than one, then you need to keep track of which FpSpread control is active yourself.