# Is it possible that changing the .ActiveControl cause RemoveControl to be called?

Tags: c#, winforms

Somewhere on _VisibleChanged event I am changing the ActiveControl:

```
private void ResultNumeric_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visible)
    {
        this.ActiveControl = this.resNumResult;
    }
}
```

Now if I follow one work flow of the program, my app is crashing. I looked at the StackTrace and it has a call to REMOVE in it which will set the Parent to null and actually crash is also coming from a place that I am calling a method on a a parent this is null.

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.AfterControlRemoved(Control control, Control oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.AfterControlRemoved(Control control, Control oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Remove(Control value)
```

So is it this change of ActiveControl that is causing the Remove method to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that setting the ActiveControl removes a control from form's ControlCollection. The error must be somewhere else. Do you have a remove of a control somewhere else in your code?

Comment: that I should do more investigation. wanted to make sure ActoveControl is not the culprit. thanks

Comment: If you find another code construct that makes you nervous, don't hasitate to make your question!

Comment: yeah, the Crash and Null Parent that I was talking about it in this question is part of the investigation I am doing to find the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139252/why-the-parent-on-a-user-control-is-null  that one is the main problem this one was part of the investigation I was doing to find the answer to that one.